# Implement all ibm Watson conversation response types(text,options, pauses, images)

Tags: types, response, chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I cloned a github android chatbot project which uses ibm Watson conversation. The Chatbot only sends text as a reply. How to get quick reply(in form of options), image and pauses as responses from watson conversation api?

Comment: It would be great of you could share the code / URL of the project you cloned. Moreover IBM Watson conversation is a text API, if you want to have quick replies, images, etc. you need to do this via your middleware.

Comment: "via your Middleware" can you elaborate please?

Comment: Here is the github link to the project.                        https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/chatbot-watson-android

Comment: A middleware would be a backend application that acts as a bridge between différents services. This could be developed in NodeJS, python, ruby, etc.

Comment: IBM conversation only take texts as input, you should convert the text to the relevant format to create a quick reply or a carousel in your middleware

Comment: I was able to retrieve quick reply(options) label name from backend(watson conversation) through java code.The label name(example-yes,no) appears as text.I want to this text in buttons,so that when a user clicks the button,a value is sent to watson conversation.How to acheive the above stated task.I am using Android Studio.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this. The first is that you need to modify the dialog to return options, images, pauses etc. Take a look at the tutorials in the service documentation - https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-tutorial#tutorial

Second the orchestration layer needs to be able to identify when options and images are being returned from the dialog and craft the UI appropriately. If you use one of the generated deployment options - https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-deploy-intercom#deploy-intercom , then the work is done for you. If you are using your own orchestration layer then you app will need to do it.

In the app you have cloned, it will be the bit that generates the UI, but it looks like the app is using android libraries to build the UI, so you might need to read up on crafting Android UIs with the Android libraries. The app receives the response in the `sendMessage()` method in `MainActivity.java` and pulls out the text response only.

The current official service demo - https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/assistant-demo - is a node.js app, which handles options, but its not a Java Android app.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @chughts.I have modified my code in sendMessage(). I was able to retrieve label name of options which is previously stored in my backend(watson conversation).

Comment: Now I have to create clickable buttons using these label names. For example, I have 3 options label name in my backend which are "sad", "content", "lonely". I need to create buttons on my chat application(using java in Android Studio) using the said option label name. Such that when user of chatbot clicks on any button a value is passed to watson conversation and dialog nodes are accessed based on the value which is passed from frontend

Comment: Now you know which bit of UI code that you need to create buttons with, you should create a new question on stack, showing your existing code, and asking how to add buttons to the UI. It will be an Android UI question.